# How can I replace some strings from the whole output of my .NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use webforms/masterpage, with .NET.

I Have many Web User Controls into my page.

Is there a point where I can made some replace in some "strings"?

Like, if .NET generate :

```
<div>Hello my Name is Marco</div>
```

changing it in :

```
<div>Hi, my Name is Luca</div>
```

Is it possible? Or I need to create my specific utility every time I get these data (from DB) and I do a response.write?

Comment: I'm telling you right now, using MVC instead of WebForms would make your life so much easier if you need to control the HTML that you generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to write an [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and hook it up to the [`PreSendRequestContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestcontent.aspx) event, and do your replacements here. Take a look at the solution presented here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1149673

Comment: All this just to put some data from your database on the page? I'm guessing the problem is as simple as that. He just wants to make part of a control to be dynamic.

Comment: @CyberDude, well, I'm just presenting a possible solution here. Sounds like the OP *wants* to replace, and not fix the problem at its root, namely in the database where, supposedly, the data could just be updated and fixed.

Comment: To me it looks more like when you log in to a website and you see "Welcome, <whatever your name is>!" somewhere in the header. No rocket science, just a string containing some dynamic data.

Comment: @CyberDude, well, we're both just guessing... I was thinking that changing the name from Marco to Luca, looked like he is trying to achieve something more than simply changing the value of some resource string.

Comment: I just have some links in my database (like http:www.mywebsite02.com) and I'd like to switch them to mywebsite03.com, on all "displayed" text...

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.Net WebForms approach would be to use a label control and set the name in the code behind.

So your aspx file would contain

```
<div>Hello my Name is <asp:Label id="NameLabel" runat="server"/></div>
```

And your code behide file ie the aspx.cs would contain

```
NameLabel.Text = "Luca"
```

And if your looking to implement something dirty its possible to modifying the HTTP response using filters. This article explains in better detail. https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx But I wouldn't recommend using this.

Answer (score 0):

using this technique you can, without recompilation, change the message shown to the user whilst keeping data, logic and ui concerns separate. It's not 'simple' but it is clean.

Disclaimer: Not written using an IDE

**Web Form**

```
<div><asp:Literal id="litHelloMessage" runat="server" text="<%=GetHelloMessage() %>" />
<asp:Literal id="litName" runat="server" text="<%=User.Name %>"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
   public User User { get; set; }

   public void Page_Load()
   {
      // logic to fetch the user from your persistence store
      // e.g. User = MyUserRepo.Fetch(uid);

      // Important
      DataBind();
   }

   public string GetHelloMessage()
   {
        // this is straight forward, alternatively you could have  some logic here to 
        // derive which which message is shown to the user
        litHelloMessage = GetLocalResourceObject(User.MessageResourceKey).ToString();
   }
}
```

**Resource File** (App_LocalResources/mypage.resx)

```
Key                  Value    
"HelloMessage"       "Hello my Name is" 
"HiMessage"          "Hi, my Name is"
```

**User Class**

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MessageResourceKey { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
Name         MessageResourceKey 
"Marco"      "HelloMessage"
"Luca"       "HiMessage"
```

Answer (score -2):

What you need is a template engine.
This is a good start from wikipedia
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_(web)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29)

Or the View part of the MVC concept as others pointed out.

There are different ways of implementing a template engine and many more ready to use ones.

Comment: This doesn't help someone using ASP.Net WebForms.

Comment: there are template engine you could plug into the asp.net routine, like the Render method Adam Naylor pointed out for example. Would you need some examples?